# How do I get JSON data in a plain c# program from a ASP.net MVC program?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, web-services

I am a newbie in asp.net MVC. I want to create a plain c# client program that consumes json returned from a asp.net mvc progam.  What is the best method for retrieving the json data from the asp.net MVC site?  I currently use WebRequst, WebResponse and StreamReader to retrieve the data.  Is this a good method, otherwise what is the best practice to get the data?  Can I use something like below? Thanks a lot

```
    WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();  
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    string urlText = reader.ReadToEnd();
    //Then parse the urlText to json object
```

Comment: My question is if it is ok to use WebRequst, WebResponse and StreamReader to get json data from a asp.net MVC program. Thanks

Comment: Without using WCF, then WebRequest would fine and is in fact the only option available to you.

Comment: As Simon stated its pretty much your only option.  You could look at the newer wcf web api classes such as HttpClient that may make a little more sense to you.  http://nuget.org/List/Packages/WebApi.All

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't parse the text to JSON object on server side because JSON is `Javascript Object Notation` and C# knows nothing about that. You parse the JSON string to a specific type. For example:

```
string json = {"Name":"John Smith","Age":34};
```

Can be deserialized to a C# class Person as so:

```
public class Person
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public int Age {get;set;}
}

JavascriptSerializer js= new JavascriptSerializer();
Person john=js.Desearialize<Person>(json);
```

Comment: That's what I am looking for. But Part of my question is if it is ok to use WebRequst, WebResponse and StreamReader to get json data from a asp.net MVC program or there is some other practice. Thanks for your time

Comment: @user394128 I don't see why not. The bottom line is that if you get get a json string on your http response you should be able to construct your objects from that json string using the Javascript Serializer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `JavaScriptSerializer` class:

```
var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var person = js.Deserialize<Person>(urlText);
```

Person, of course, should be replaced by your own .NET type. [Here's also an article that might help you](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rakkimk/archive/2009/01/30/asp-net-json-serialization-and-deserialization.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Well, one way is:

```
var dictionary = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(urlText);
```

You can use different types than a dictionary, but whether you *should* depends on why you're actually doing this.